# PIC microcontroller programmer/debugger tools for beginner

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am a final year student and am going to use a PIC device for my project, so am getting familiar with it early.

1. I will be using MPLAB X IDE to program the PIC. How is the code actually downloaded onto the microcontroller? I have read that the 'PIC KIT 3' programmer/debugger is the easiest.
2. With the PIC KIT 3, is it possible to debug online in real time and see the status of I/O pins and registers etc?
3. What other methods are available to program a PIC?

Comment: PIC is a **really** large microcontroller family. Which one specifically are you considering? If the answer is "don't know, any one?!", then my follow up recommendation is not to use one of the classical PICs for your project but to directly go to one of the thousands rich-peripheral, rich-memory, low-power, high-speed ARM microcontrollers, many of which,  unlike the PICs, come with a bootloader in system ROM, which makes flashing them a whole lot easier. 8-bit PICs and their beefier cousins have their niche in some low-power, or low-cost, or speciality applications, but don't complicate…

Comment: … your final year project by restricting your microcontroller to low resources. For a one-off project, using PICs is typically not even a cost-effective choice.

Comment: David, what is the final yr proj (or capstone?) It would help us help you evaluate the your processor choice to know details. And what is the processor you are currently examining? If you use the PIC, then yes MPLAB X IDE is probably the right IDE to use for development. Regarding tools, I use MPLAB REAL ICE (and appropriate kits for the device.) What's appropriate in your case varies. You can get demo boards with a socket that can program some devices for you. You can use PICkits (I have v2, v3, not yet v4.) Microchip supports professional devices and CPUs, forever. Not so, hobbyist stuff.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I haven't picked a specific uC yet. Was thinking of getting a more basic 8 or 16 bit product to get the hang of the software / programming before I start my project. The only thing that puts me off the high spec ARM uC's is the fact they are surface mounted.

Comment: @jonk It is to provide the processing logic for a 3 phase generator controller. There will be a digital automatic voltage regulator and speed governor with ideally an HMI touch screen display to display all machine information as well as alarms etc. I haven't definitely decided on  PIC product. I am finding it very difficult to pick a uC manufacturer. The PIC with the PIC KIT and MPLAB X IDE just seems easy to use and reliable, but would be easily convinced to use another brand uC.

Comment: @David777 My experience as a developer with a wide variety of manufacturers has led me to conclude that Microchip is always the partner I want to have, unless technical details force me elsewhere (for example, for extreme low-power I may go to the MSP430.) They support their tools, without equivocation. They support my development. They provide very good professional level tools. Etc. They stand out uniquely against a much poorer background of "others." But you have to focus on what you need to achieve, and how quickly, and then match this up with what's available to you. No bright lines.

Comment: You might want to look at Microchip's former Atmel line, particularly chips such as the SAME70 series. For dealing with 3-phase state space control and such like it's nice to have good PWM peripherals with enough features and an on-chip FPU. You can use an eval board to deal with the SMT issue or just learn to solder a SMT (non-BGA) package, it's not all that hard, especially for those with young eyes or a good microscope.

Comment: @jonk At this stage I have plenty of time so would like to select a brand that can offer different performance levels with the same software programming platform so changing uC model is quite easy. My problem is that I haven't went into enough detail with my project yet to know what performance specs I require. But also don't want to waste a month not becoming familiar with a software platform e.g. PIC, ARM

Comment: @SpehroPefhany These sound like they could be very useful to me, I will take a look at them. I think what you are saying is actually correct, surface mounting is only an excuse. I can learn how to do it, after all, the whole point of the project is to learn something.

Comment: @David777 Most manufacturers have something useful regarding 3-phase motor controls (e.g., [MSP430](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa503/slaa503.pdf). (The MSP430 includes some incredible timers.) There are even application notes on [Using a PIC for Speed Control of Three Phase Induction Motor Using Single Phase Supply](http://ijrcsit.org/images/P9-059.pdf). An important part of this process will be learning how to research what's available and make choices! But in the end, the important skill isn't *making the best decision* but instead being able to ***succeed with the decision you do make.***

Comment: @David777 True in business as in any project: If you can avoid making a fatal mistake, then you survive. People worry too much about "looking foolish." What's important is to do enough research so that you can probably succeed even if some guesswork is wrong. Make the decision before all the cards are in. You will have more research to do early in the project to resolve other unknowns and you need to get to that sooner not later.  What ultimately matters isn't about ***always making the optimal decision*** but instead being able to ***always succeed given the decisions you actually do make***.

Comment: @jonk Yes I think you are correct. I think I will stick with the PIC and MPLAB X ICE for the time being. Do you know of the top of your head is the PIC KIT 4 programs all or most PIC microcontrollers?

Comment: @David777 I don't. I have v2 and v3. (I don't use them much, though.)

Comment: @David777 Programming the microcontroller is only a part of development. Debugging is another. The professional tools provide more information when you find you need it (long trace buffers, for example.) You won't get some software or hardware features in the hobbyist tools. If you feel you can succeed with the project using simple debugging and using hacks like adding an LED to an I/O pin to help you debug, then the hobbyist tools are enough. But success is your ultimate goal. So if you have the budget, avoid the tool being the risky barrier that leads to failure and get professional tools.

Comment: @jonk Sorry, I haven't used them before either. Do you class the PIC kits as hobbyist tools or professional tools?

Comment: @David777 The PICkits are not professional tools. Microchip itself makes these distinctions. Not you. They offer low-cost tools to help lower the investment needed for basic hobbyist work and for professionals surveying MCU options during a research stage of a project. They are good tools for those purposes. But they provide only a useful subset of their full development capabilities. If you want the ability to trigger on some event and then look backwards for the last 1000 instructions to see how you got there, for example? You'll need professional tools. You may not need all that, though.

Comment: @David777 Microchip supports their professional tools forever. They also support their MCUs, similarly forever. For example, I can still buy the very first PIC chip I ever used -- the PIC16C54. Even though it is many DECADES old, now. They will build their chips forever. And they still support the ICE 2000, which is also ancient. If my ICE 2000 develops so much as a "switch problem," they will replace it free the next day with overnight shipping and a prepaid box to return my old unit to them. Etc. That support doesn't apply to PICkits, though.

Comment: @jonk Ah ok, I see. Although I believe at my level of embedded systems at the present moment that the hobbyist equipment will be adequate for my project. I will do a bit more research into what 'hobbyist' MCU to use.

Comment: also worth looking at ICD3 or ICD4 which you can get for " a few dollars more". I would read around reviews and the experiences of others as they all have pros and cons. I use ICD3 myself, quite happy with it.

Comment: I know that this is not part of the question but I would like to hear your thoughts on the tm4c123 development boards. I used them for a module in university previously and liked them. They are pretty well spec’d. I would be using the kiel micro vision programming/debugging software. They are quite cheap as well

Comment: Better ask a new question about the tool

Answer (score 2):

The PICKit3 is a little bit old as @Marcus already mentioned and not really recommended.
If you are looking for a easy, fast and also cheap debugger/programmer have a look at the [MPLAB Snap.](https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/PartNO/PG164100)

Comment: This looks like what I need. I will take a look in more detail today. Thank you

Comment: I guess there is a 50% discount on that tool, so you will pay less then 10€ .https://www.microchipdirect.com/product/search/all/PG164100

Answer (score 0):

As with any microcontroller, you'll need some kind of hardware interface to load the program code onto it.

Often, such interfaces also assume the rule of Debug Interface.

> I have read that the 'PIC KIT 3' programmer/debugger is the easiest.

well, I don't know that one. But if it's [this one](https://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails/PG164130), then its website says

> The PICkit 3 is not recommended for new designs and no new device support will be added to it as of June 1, 2019. For new designs, please see the MPLAB PICKit 4.

And I'd argue that yeah, don't go for something that the manufacturer explicitly states desire to drop support.

Anyway, from the description:

> Microchip’s PICkit™ 3 In-Circuit Debugger/Programmer

yeah, so it's a programmer and debugger. Check.

> With the PIC KIT 3, is it possible to debug online in real time and see the status of I/O pins and registers etc?

That would be the purpose of a debugger. I doubt the both of us have the same understanding of the term "real time", because such microcontrollers run at megahertzes and you can't see that fast, but yeah, I'd presume that's the case, together with adequate software, which I guess the MPLAB X IDE is.